# Anyway to animate smoothly on mobile device with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

Upon loading a reasonably long page, I need to smoothly scroll down to a certain  on the page, so that the user doesn't have to.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#today').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});

...
<div id="today">foo</div>
```

This works well in a desktop browser, but on the iPhone and especially on the Android, it is pretty jerky.

Questions:

1. Am I going about it the right way?  Is there a better way?
2. Is there a way to specify a specific interval in milliseconds, instead of 'slow'?

Comment: 1. depends on what you think is "jerky"
2. yes, just use 1000 instead of 'slow' or any other number

Comment: @monkeyinsight I tried using a large number and it had zero effect.

Comment: check documentation http://api.jquery.com/animate/ it works there

Comment: You also may try this library https://github.com/gnarf/jquery-requestAnimationFrame it replaces `setTimeout` function, which not correspond to possible FPS on device, by `requestAnimationFrame` which is more modern approach for animation. And by the way, I don't recommend using jQuery at all, because it's very "jerky" by itself and slow down site

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `.animate()` `easing` options appear set to `swing` by default , try setting to `linear` , e.g.,

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#today').offset().top
    }, 2000, "linear");
});
```

```css
#today {
  position : absolute;
  top : 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="today">today</div>
```